# chrome extention popup window automatically closed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i create a simple chrome extention that take a image as an input from the user ... after that i upload that image to cloudinary through api call ...
but the problem is when i open popup and select a image atfer that popup window is automatically close. when i open it again it will refresh and my selected image file was gone

this is my popup.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>My Chrome Extension</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <form action="">

   <div style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">           
     <h3>Hello,</h3>
     <p>Please enter your name : </p>         
     <input id="name_textbox" type="file" value="" />  
     <button id="btn" > submit</button>   
     <a href="">click here</a>              
     
 </div>  
 </form>

 <script src="popup.js"></script>

 
</body>
</html>
```

this is my popup.js

```
const input = document.getElementById('name_textbox')
const link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click',check)
function check(e){
e.preventDefault()
  const  val = input.files[0];
 

 const form = new FormData();

    form.append("file", val);
    form.append("upload_preset" , 'unsigned_name')
    const url = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/name/image/upload"
  fetch(url , {
    method: "POST",
    body:form
    
  }).then((res)=> res.json()).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
    link.href = res.url
  })
  
  
 
}
```

anyone can please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Remove `form` tag.

Comment: nothing much happen wnen i remove form tag

Comment: Show you popup.js and the new popup.html please.

Comment: i update i question pease check it out

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome: the file input closes the popup. You'll have to open a separate window using chrome.windows.create inside chrome.action.onClicked listener in the background script - instead of using `default_popup` in manifest.json.

Comment: thanks for answering my question can you please share any blog or yt video link related to this topic that will very help full to me